# Implementing private video chat rooms onto a website

Tags: javascript, api, video, frontend, chat

I want to implement a private video chat room software onto my website. Like Google Meet without the bells and whistles (just video calling with a shareable private link).

I found an open source platform called Daily.co. Should I use this? What technical requirements would I need to hire a developer for? What would be the cost of a project like this?

Answer (score 1):

I work at Daily so I can try to help answer this. We have two options (Custom or [Daily Prebuilt](https://www.daily.co/prebuilt), which can just be embedded right into your website or made full screen to fill the page). Prebuilt covers the use case you described and you'd really just need a dev comfortable with basic JavaScript (we've intentionally made this as easy to embed as possible.)
There's a custom option too if you want the video call UI to have a specific design, so that would take a dev with a bit more experience. :)

Comment: Hi Jessica, thank you for your reply! Is there any technical requirements in terms of infrastructure? We currently have a Wix website, nothing else.

Comment: That should be fine! :) I haven't tested this myself with Wix but a colleague shared this information with me: "You will need to configure your Wix site to allow for camera and mic permissions, and then pass those permissions to the frame containing the Daily call. We have learned from other customers that this requires a Premium Plan on Wix."